# Azure web app access through VNet with certificates on gateway

Tags: networking, azure, web, web-applications

My goal is to have a Web App in a VNet which goes through a VNet gateway using certificates to grant access to the web app. My test uses a standard image in Azure (Node.js). I have followed "Configure a Point-to-Site connection to a VNet using native Azure certificate authentication: Azure portal" documentation for setting up the VNet, Subnets (front end and GatewaySubnet) Certificates, and Gateway and can connect to the gateway. I’ve verified connection to the VNet with ipconfig/all as suggested, and indeed I am connected. The web app shows when I connect directly without putting it in the VNet.

I set the Web App to deny all except the IP address from the VNet gateway. The web app shows a 503 error when connected to the VNet subnet "frontend" which I created, as well as when I connect the web app to the gateway subnet.

Should I be using a route table? If so, could you give some help with that since I haven’t been able to get a handle on how that might work.
Thank you,
Ken